# Prove that X/Y/Z is context-free

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

Given languages X, Y and Z, each with alphabet, define X/Y/Z 
 as:

```
     X/Y/Z = { w ∈ Σ* | ∃u ∈ Y and ∃v ∈ Z; such that wuv ∈ X }.
```

Prove that if X is context-free, and Y and Z are regular, then X/Y/Z
is context-free.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: This is a pure exercise dump. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a discussion why we think your question is bad, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) for questions you should check out before asking. Once you include your own attempts, you have posted a question in its own right that can be answered to solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $T = YZ$, your language is the set $L$ of all $w \in \Sigma^*$ for which there is a $t \in T$ such that $wt \in X$. In other words, $L$ is the right quotient of $X$ by $T$. Now, if $X$ is regular, so is $L$ (in all cases) and if $X$ is context-free and $Y$ and $Z$ are regular, then $T$ is regular and $L$ is context-free. One way to prove this latter statement is to consider the rational transduction $\tau$ defined by $\tau(u) = uT$ and observe that $L = \tau^{-1}(X)$. Now, the inverse of a rational transduction is also a rational transduction and context-free languages are preserved under rational transductions.

For an introduction to transductions see [J. Berstel, Transductions and
Context-Free Languages](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/LivreTransductions/LivreTransductions14dec2009.pdf).

Comment: @J.-E. Pin plz post another solution other than not involving rational transduction function..bcoz i didn't know about rational transduction

Comment: @user561298: Why should they? You did not show any effort, so be glad you receive any answer. It is not anybody's job to come up with an answer that will solve your homework. If you want an answer more suitable for your needs, you should elaborate your question.

Comment: @Raphel..let me tell u it is not any homework problem..this question already appeared of my recently exams..i want to know the solution(eagerly) that's it!!